# Не отображаются изображение в "медиафайлах" wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Переношу статьи со старого сайта на новый сайт. Залил изображения на прямую в папку по датам как на старом сайте. Захожу админка нового сайта - медиафайлы, залитые файлы не отображаются. Скажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть причина?

Comment: Информация о медиафайлах в базе, файлы там все прописаны

Comment: Причина в неправильно переносе Изучай: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress/767562#767562

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему перенес с помощью плагина https://wordpress.org/plugins/export-featured-images/